# ChartJS: Translate x axis month to other languages

Tags: angularjs, localization, chart.js, momentjs

I'm having difficulties in finding out how to translate the time axis. I'm using `MMM YYYY` for time displayFormats in xAxes.

It always displays date like `May 2018`. Does anyone know how to localize here?

For example, if the language is french, the month should be displayed as Mai instead of May. I searched everywhere, only find someone said it is possible to do that using time.parser, but I am not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem in my Ruby on Rails application.

We don't use angularjs, but I think the way of using Chart.js is very similar.

I will post the way I managed it to work in Ruby on Rails and polish locale. But you should be able to easy customize the solution to work with Angular.js

1. Include moment.js locale in the JavaScript bundle apart of moment.js library

```
//= require moment
//= require moment/pl.js
```

2. Add custom displayFormats to make it easier to parse date in callback function. And add callback function to parse and format date again.

```
options: {
                    ...
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                              displayFormats: {
                               'hour': 'HH:mm',
                               'day': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                               'week': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                               'month': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                              },
                              unit: '<%= @report.scale %>',
                            },
                            ticks: {
                              callback: function(value, index) {
                                let displayFormats = {
                                  'hour': 'HH:mm',
                                  'day': 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                                  'week': 'YYYY WW',
                                  'month': 'MMMM YYYY',
                                };
                                let unit = '<%= @report.scale %>';
                                let format = displayFormats[unit];
                                return moment(value, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format(format, value);
                              }
                            }
                        }],
```

For some reason moment.js inside of Chart.js ignores locales. But when calling moment.js again inside of the callback function it works well.

I added guard return for all units other than month. I didn't want to reparse and reformat dates other than months.